# ASP.NET MVC How to implement timer functionality to update dock panels on client side respective to their time intervals?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, timer, setinterval

I have encountered a problem of updating dock panels on client side ( browser ).
After time interval elapses, I have to send callback to update the contents of dock panel.

Each and every dock panel can have own respective time interval that can be set/reset by the user by interacting it's settings module. Thus we can have something like

dock panel_a : update after 10s

dock panel_b : update after 5s

dock panel_c : update after 15s

...............................

later on user might can change all the timers and these module might update totally on different intervals. I might be ended up having 100's of dock panels and correspondingly 70's would  update their contents and 30 might never update Or 30 would update and 70 would be set to Never update.

What would be right implementation??

Should I write complete server side functionality ( in this case, I would write delegates or complete asynchronous implementation for updating all modules available on client side )??

Should I maintain a list of available panels at client side and need to access that list for sending callback once the time interval elapse for specific dock panel?  If so, I would definitely need a parent timer available on client browser window which would count the seconds and on completion of seconds, it will match and refer the previously maintain list. If so,

List might contain 50 panels corresponding 50 timer objects..
Would that be fine?

Note:
I am more in a favour of implementing server side code ( delegates and asynchronous ) because my server side better knows how many dock panels rendered on screen and for each dock panel it can maintain thread to update dock panel on client side.

what should be the right way?

Regards

Usman

Comment: Ignoring bad design you would need to use Ajax to update Server side

Comment: perhaps you totally ignore my logic. that was actually my business logic :-P
you can call it bad..But I have user click able dock panels on client side and those can update their contents on the basis of user choice ( i.e 5s,10s, 30s or NeverUpdate )